# How to pull collectionGroups in Flutter Firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here's a build:

[image]

Here I want to pull all the collections inside the document. How can I do that?

---

I tried a code like this:

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("Mission1").get().then((value) {
    value.docs.forEach((doc) {
      print(doc.data()["title"].toString());
    });
  });
```

But in this code, I need to enter the collection name. Before I go in, I want to pull all collections.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can't from web and mobile clients.  Read the dups for more information.

Answer (score 1):

that's undoable in firebase according to the documentation:

> Retrieving a list of collections is not possible with the mobile/web
> client libraries. You should only look up collection names as part of
> administrative tasks in trusted server environments. If you find that
> you need this capability in the mobile/web client libraries, consider
> restructuring your data so that subcollection names are predictable.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document

you should build your data structure in way that doesn't need this requirement, although you can make some solutions like storing all subcollections names inside your doc, but that wouldn't be efficient in real-life applications.

Comment: @tarep albeesh My purpose is to pull data named `title` inside subcollections. So is this possible?

Comment: if you mean that `title` is inside Mission1,Mission2 , Mission3... etc, that's undoable with firebase built-in fetching methods.

Comment: @tarep albeesh `title` exists in all collections. My goal is to make a to-do-list implementation. Each of the subcollections represents a task.

Comment: your data structure wouldn't serve your goal, you need to change your data structuring. I recommend you read this article from the firebase team:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data
and I think this video also would make things more clear:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=haMOUb3KVSo